# How to configure WinSCP with SSH proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel, winscp

I'm trying to configure WinSCP for use with a proxy so that I can Login to my site (I'm trapped behind a corporate firewall). I'm trying to follow the directions of https://www.javahotchocolate.com/notes/winscp.html to tunnel through a proxy and connect to an EC2 instance with WinSCP.

From the directions in the article I have set the proxy settings like so:

[image]

But I am confused as to how to set the tunnel settings. I tried the same info but got:

> Proxy error: 403 forbidden

Comment: It'd be cool if you could select @martin-prikryl answer if it led you to a solution.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are using target server (EC2) details for proxy settings.

It should be the other way around. Use your corporate proxy details for proxy settings and use your target server details on the [Login dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login).

Moreover, you mention that you want to use an SSH proxy, what is commonly called an SSH tunnel. The [tunnel has separate page on Advanced Site Settings dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_tunnel).

See also the WinSCP guide to [Connecting to FTP/SFTP server which can be accessed via another server only](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel).